# Moralis estimating wrong gas

Tags: javascript, ethereum, moralis

I have a function I'm calling using [Moralis](https://moralis.io/):

JavaScript

```
let tx = await Moralis.executeFunction({
        functionName: 'mint_cats',
        params: { amount },
        msgValue: cat_price * amount,
        ...options,
      })
```

And I have a local version running, and a version deployed to the moralis servers. The gas costs of the edition I'm running locally, look normal:

[image]

However, the gas costs of the deployed front end, are insane:

[image]

What's going on?